# Python Error 24: too many files open: Per Process Limit?

Tags: python, csv

When using this py code to split a large csv into smaller csv's (about ) I am receiving the error:

"OSError: [Error 24] Too Many Open Files:"

After running this there should be 29,930 separate files, however its stopping after 2048.

I have done some research and it looks like there is a per process limit of 2048. How can I get around this?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import binascii
    import csv
    import os.path
    import sys
    from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
    from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

    def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        header = next(csv_reader)
        csv_writers = {}
        for row in csv_reader:
            k = keyfunc(row)
if k not in csv_writers:
            writer = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k),
                                             mode='w', newline=''))
            writer.writerow(header)
            csv_writers[k] = writer
        csv_writers[k].writerow(row[0:1])

    def get_args_from_cli():
        input_filename = sys.argv[1]
        column = int(sys.argv[2])
        dst_dir = sys.argv[3]
        return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

    def get_args_from_gui():
        input_filename = askopenfilename(
            filetypes=(('CSV', '.csv'),),
            title='Select CSV Input File')
        column = askinteger('Choose Table Column', 'Table column')
        dst_dir = askdirectory(title='Select Destination Directory')
        return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        if len(sys.argv) == 1:
            input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_gui()
        elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
            input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_cli()
        else:
            raise Exception("Invalid number of arguments")
        with open(input_filename, mode='r', newline='') as f:
            split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: r[column-1]+'.csv')
            # if the column has funky values resulting in invalid filenames
            # replace the line from above with:
            # split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: binascii.b2a_hex(r[column-1].encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')+'.csv')
```

Comment: i don't know the answer, but is there a reason you need all 29,930 files open at the same time? you could just close them as you go surely?

Comment: The files are split based on the value of the second column. So I fear if I close the files and there is another line with an already closed file it will overwrite.

Comment: you can append to files, meaning you just add to the data already there if the file exists (and create it if it doesn't) but i'm note sure how you'd do that in the context of a csv writer.

Comment: Use `'a'` mode instead of `'w'` to append to files without overwriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep the `csv` writers in a dictionary. You can re-open the file to append to it:

Replace:

```
if k not in csv_writers:
    csv_writers[k] = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k),
                                     mode='w', newline=''))
csv_writers[k].writerow(row)
```

With:

```
filename = os.path.join(dst_dir, k)
with open(filename, mode='a', newline='') as output:
    csv.writer(output).writerow(row)
```